# Tablelayout and LinearLayout - visible and invisble

Tags: tablelayout

I want to have a table layout inside a linear layout so that there is text before and after the table layout. The issue is that I want to be able to switch between 2 tables (Table1 and Table2) but keep the text before and after the same. I thought that this would be manageable using visible and invisible features of tablelayout and define the whole thing in one layout but this doesnt seem to be the case. What I get is that when I make Table2 visible and Table1 invisble that Table2 is shifted down because I have defined it after Table 1 in the layout.

What I want is:-
SomeTextHere
Table1
SomeTextHere too

or

SomeTextHere
Table2
SomeTextHere too

What I get is:-

SomeTextHere
Table1
SomeTextHere too

SomeTextHere

Table2
SomeTextHere too

I have tried:-

LinearLayout
TableLayout1 make visible
TableLayout2 make invisible
LinearLayout

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question correctly i think what you can do is adding two more LinearLayout in your main LinearLayout.Then put the group (Text,Table,Text) in each LinearLayout and then you can work with each Linear Layout instead of working with text,table,text

So that your layout hierarchy looks like

```
< LinearLayout>

        < LinearLayout>

             < Text>
             < TableLayout>
             < Text>

    < /LinearLayout>

    < LinearLayout>

            < Text>
            < TableLayout>
            < Text
     < /LinearLayout>

    < /LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear. The text will remain the same - only the data in the table layout will change. In your solution are you making the LinearLayouts visible and invisible rather than just the TableLayouts?

Comment: i thought you need to work with full bunch like text,table,text.so i put it on a layout.So that if you want you can hide altogether

Comment: Okay, let me try again. I have some TextViews before and after the TableLayout and so I am trying to avoid  having 2 TextView IDs. The same text will be displayed before and after the table and so I imagined I could use only 1 ID for each TextView before and after rather than having 2 (one for each layout in your suggestion above). I am trying to make a golf score card and so I want the name of player to remain constant at top and his total score remain constant at bottom. In the middle is a table which switches between 1-9 and 10-18 nine holes that will change.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're using View.INVISIBLE to hide the sections.  You need to use View.GONE if you want a view to not take up space in a layout.

Also if only the table is changed then you don't need to duplicate just put the tables one after the other and set the visibility of the one that shouldn't be visible by default set to gone.  Then you can just toggle them in code.